# More Optimized way instead of import * as firebase from 'firebase'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,) {

  }
```

**Use case 1:**

```
createdDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

**Use case 2:**

```
 const result: firebase.auth.UserCredential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

For above I need to import this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Since `firebase` is a very big JS library I would like to do it in a more optimized way. Can you tell me how to do that?

**Note:** Here I use `AngularFire`. But how can I get these models? `firebase.auth.UserCredential`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want clean import and optimized import, I suggest to use the official library for angular with firebase: [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) wich is well documented and up to date.

And inside for the interfaces or class, you can use probably:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

And still continue to use : `firebase.auth.UserCredential` in your code

Comment: Yes, I use `AngularFire`. But how can I get these models: `firebase.auth.UserCredential`

Comment: @Sampath good point! I have updated my answer according to this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/388)

Comment: That too gave me this error: `Module '"d:/Clients/node_modules/firebase/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag`. But your link was great. I have used this `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` Please update your answer too. Thanks.

Comment: This can still be optimized more. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the docs for Angularfire and firebase.

You can import things from `firebase/app` and get access to each object.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';


 const result: auth.UserCredential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between this `import * as firebase from '@firebase/app';` and this `import { auth } from 'firebase/app';`? I feel no difference.

Comment: Because both have same namespace no? i.e. `firebase/app`

Comment: This is not working too? `createdDate: auth.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),`

Comment: 1) 'firebase' vs '@firebase'. One is the correct import path, one is not. You do not import from `@firebase`.

2) Again, i'd say look at the docs. The angularfire docs have reference to doing things this way.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. This is the Typescript way: `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` Please see this: https://imgur.com/j8RqmdJ

Comment: Otherwise, I cannot do this: `createdDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),`